# Allow filtering of loops for all categories

Tags: theme-development, query-posts

I want to give the option to filter the index page and every archive page for a category by things like newest, top-rated, most-viewed. I know how to filter a loop for each of those but I need a solution for switching to each filtered loop.

Comment: Close voted as _not constructive_: »This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.«

Comment: I changed the last question so it should be good. Im just looking for a solution that is efficient.

Comment: How about linking the question and telling "it is a follow up"?

Comment: What you're asking involves multiple questions and research avenues, e.g. how to track view counts, how to rate posts, how to show the posts with the most views for solution X, how to show posts ordered by rank etc etc, I can easily see 3 questions here, not one

Comment: Oh sorry I know how to do all the filtering and should have stated that. I just need to know a way to switch back and forth to loops with different filters.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, within the scope of how to filter the primary loop query according to some pre-defined filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend defining a **query var** to define your custom filters, and then pass the (sanitized) value of that query var to `query_posts()` (to alter the primary Loop, if that is your ojbective).

First (in `functions.php`), define your query var:

```
<?php
function wpse47974_queryvars( $qvars )
{
$qvars[] = 'wpse47974_filter';
return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse47974_queryvars' );
?>
```

Next, in the template, query your query var. I'll assume that you have a pre-defined set of filters, defined in an array, `$wpse47974_valid_filters`:

```
<?php
// Query Tag Filter
$wpse47974_filter = '';
if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['wpse47974_filter'] ) && in_array( $wp_query->query_vars['wpse47974_filter'], $wpse47974_valid_filters ) ) {
    $wpse47974_filter = $wp_query->query_vars['wpse47974_filter'];
}
?>
```

Next (somewhere), you'll need to define your query parameters based on your filter types. I leave this as an exercise for the OP; however, in the following code, these query parameters are represented by "`$wpse47974_filter_args['key'] => 'value';`", and we add them to an array, here (in the template file):

```
<?php
// Define an empty array to hold our filter parameters.
// This needs to be an array, in order not to generate 
// errors later in the array_merge(), if no filter parameters
// are being applied to the default query
$wpse47974_filter_args = array();

// If our query var is set, apply the filter parameter
if ( '' != $wpse47974_filter  ) {
    $wpse47974_filter_args['key'] = 'value';
};    
?>
```

Next, still in the template file, merge the default query with our filter parameters above, to modify `query_posts()` (note: *before* outputting the Loop):

```
<?php
// Globalize $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// Merge the default query with our filter parameters
$wpse47974_query_posts_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $wpse47974_filter_args );
// Modify the default query
query_posts( $wpse47974_query_posts_args );
?>
```

Now, the primary loop query is modified as per your filter.

#### Edit

I forgot an important part: how to get the query vars into the URL!

In your template, where you have your filter links (or buttons, or whatever), I assume you have an HTML anchor. Set the `href` attribute as follows, using the [`add_query_arg()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg):

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( array( 'wpse47974_filter' => 'value' ) ); ?>">FILTER NAME</a>
```

Now, when you click the link, the page is reloaded, with your query var appended to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. Im alittle confused about applying it in a template. So say I have an index loop that shows all the latest posts and 2 buttons that I want a user to be able to click to change the loop to sort by either top-rated or most-viewed. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to add that part. See edited answer.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Ughh I must be doing something wrong. It says unexpected double arrow on 17 of this pastebin. http://pastebin.com/4Hxn1eE8

Comment: I just corrected a syntax error (check the history for the specific change). Without seeing the Pastebin, I'm *guessing* that was your problem.

Comment: Ok can you look at the pastebin. I don't think I'm implementing the custom $args correctly but because when I switch the loop doesnt change

Comment: I can later, but am unable to right at the moment...

Comment: When I click a filter and it refreshes I get an error saying `Warning: in_array() []: Wrong datatype for second argument in function.in-` on line 17 which is the second line of the `query tag filter` in the example above.

Comment: What does your array of valid filters look like?

Comment: Sorry this is like a new language. Am I suppose to replace the `$wpse47974_valid_filters` with the my default filters like `post_per_page=6` and then add the custom filters where `key` is for each value?

Comment: No, `$wpse47974_valid_filters` is intended to be an *array*, that holds names for your filter criteria, such as `'recent_posts'`, or `'popular_posts'`, etc. (Sanitizing using this method is important, because it prevents a potential SQL injection vector that would exist if users could pass arbitrary strings into your query var.)

Comment: Ok so I don't change anything there. Where do I put the deafult values of the loop that stay constant and where do I enter the custom values I want to change?

Comment: Okay, I'm looking at your Pastebin; where do you *define* the `$wpse47974_valid_filters` array? (I can pop into chat for a few minutes...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2997/discussion-between-pollux-khafra-and-chip-bennett)